# Check if String contains tab plus any non white space character

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to check if a given `String` starts with  a given amount of `tabs` + any `character` BUT `white-space-character`. This is what I tried but it is not working:

```
public static boolean hasCorrectIndentation(String line, String tabs) {
    return line.matches(tabs + "\\S+"); 
}
```

**Example 1:**

```
hasCorrectIndentation("public class inputFile {", ""))
```

*OUTPUT*: `false`

**Example 2:**

```
hasCorrectIndentation("    public class inputFile {", "\t"))
```

*OUTPUT*:  `false`

Comment: What is in `tabs`, and in what way is it "not working"?

Comment: @Nick  `tabs` contains an amount of `\t`

Comment: @Nick didnt solve the issue

Comment: @Nick I updated my question, maybe that helps? The example should return `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that [`String.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) (which is equivalent to [`Pattern.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches-java.lang.String-java.lang.CharSequence-)) effectively adds start and end of string anchors to your regex. From the documentation for [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> The matches method attempts to match the **entire** input sequence against the pattern.

So

```
line.matches(tabs + "\\S+")
```

is equivalent to

```
line.matches("^" + tabs + "\\S+$")
```

and since you have spaces in the rest of the line (after `public`) the match fails. You need to allow for spaces after the first non-space character, using something like:

```
line.matches(tabs + "\\S.*")
```

Comment: Nick, your answer is working but I still have problems with my code. I updated my answer. The thing is that I am reading `lines` from a `Java-File`  and the 2nd example is what I actually get inside `Eclipse`. It is not showing the `\t`  but instead `4 white-spaces` EVEN THOUGH inside the `Java-File` I used a `\t`.

Comment: @Chris that will be problematic... perhaps you could try something like this, which allows for all tabs being replaced with 4 spaces: https://ideone.com/Q7kMO9

Comment: @Chris no worries. If that code worked for you, I'll add it to the answer